# Django Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account

Tags: django

I have created the superuser before the deployment of app on Heroku server
my domain is gizga.herokuapp.com when u enter gizga.herokuapp.com/admin a Django Admin dashboard comes and then u have to enter the username and password but it shows the following error "Django Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account Note that both fields"
even I have created the superuser

Comment: *How* did you create the superuser before the deployment of the app?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to create superuser. Make sure you ran this command:

`(venv)$ heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`

Ensure that you use correct username and password.